# How to split mp3\wav speech to separate phonems?

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

We have over 100000 speech samples in different languanges. We want to make some dialectical research. For this target we need to split speeches to separate phonems to compare them later.

How we can do it?

We need library (better for .net) or service or alghoritm or open source software to implement this in our software.

Thanks!

Comment: are you asking how to chop audio or how to identify phonems ?

Comment: Scott, I asking how to identify phonems

Comment: do you have(or would like) an algorithm or rather the approach of having/getting a dataset of known phoneme audio snippets from which you would bounce against your supplied speech samples ?

Comment: Yea, I want approach to getting a dataset of phonemes

Comment: you can always get the ball rolling by manually creating your own snippets ... listen to a recording (say with Audacity or similar) ...  identify the start and end points of the phoneme which you save as its own snippet file ...  to craft a handful which you can then use to bounce against your supplied speech samples

Comment: oh, it's seems as very hard way, becase I must do it for every speech record. is there another ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can try aubio: http://aubio.org/
The "transient / steady-state separation" feature could be used for segmentation, and the MFCC for classification / identification.